# References needed to use Open XML from within .net web application

Tags: .net, xml, ms-word

I'm about to give up with Word automation from within a .net application and am going to try using Open XML.

It seems I need references to:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging
using DocumentFormat.OpenXm;l.Packaging;
```

After a bit of ferreting around I found you need to add a reference to Windows Base to get System.IO.Packaging to appear.

What do you need to reference to get to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging? I can't find it anywhere. I thought you might have to reference something like Microsoft.Office but that is not available either.

Comment: Just for clarity, do you have the Open XML Sdk installed ? I guess only reference to that and windows.base is needed. (At least I've used only them). Anyway, take a look also to OpenXMLPowerTools, is quite a usefull library for dealing with Open XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my latest project (ASP.NET MVC3) I've referenced these:

- DocumentFormat.OpenXML => from [Open XML Sdk](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)
- WindowsBase
- System.Xml

As stated previous in comment, you need to download and install Open XML Sdk in order to see the Assembly and reference it.

PS: Take a look at [Open XML Powertools](http://powertools.codeplex.com/) project, it's a library (I guess it's available via nuget) that will ease a bit your work.

Comment: Thanks to you and BigMike for your answers. Am I right in thinking this will only work with (thinking about Word documents) .docx and won't work with .doc? Will it work on a site developed in VS2005 accessing the .net 2.0 framework? I have a different machine with VS2010 - but the web site I need to open Word documents from (and extract their contents and stick them in a new Word document) is developed in VS2005 and frameword 2.0.

Comment: Don't really know if the Sdk is compatible with 2.0 .NET, I guess the only way to check is trying. For the format, well, yes, it will work only for docx, however even old version of word (I think from 2003 up) can read them (via a filter plugin). Once it can be opened, then it can be saved to binary word version. (At least that was our idea when we started).